# How to expand a line to make a rectangle or region

Tags: c#, graphics, line, region

I am working on .net2 so dont have access to the Line class in .net3, though im not sure if that will work.

But I have a line (2 points)

and i want to expand it to width of 4 i.e. like the drawLine Does on Graphics,
but i cannot find an easy way to get the region/ graphics path or rectangle for this.

anyone know?
and it the line can be in any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do this,

```
GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath();
gfxPath.AddLine(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2);
gfxPath.Widen(new Pen(Color.Blue, lineThickness));//lineThinkness is all that matters
Region reg = new Region(gfxPath);

if (reg.IsVisible(mousePoint)) // return true if the mousePoint is within the Region.
```

this widens the line by lineThickness, and you can then use it to check if a point or rect etc is within it.